# Modules imported in AppModule aren't visible in different modules

Tags: angular

Let's say that this is my AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see I declared `MaterialModule` over the `HomeModule`, then I exported that `MaterialModule`.
But still in `HomeModule` I cannot use components from `MaterialModule`, error:

```
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

So I'm forced to import `MaterialModule` again in `HomeModule`. Is it correct behavior or I'm doing something wrong?

---

I changed Imports in `AppModule` as @maryrio7 suggested and now is `MaterialModule.forRoot()`, and I added static method to `MaterialModule`, still doesn't work.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatIconModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        MatButtonModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatIconModule
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: MaterialModule,
            providers: []
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in Stackblitz ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Umm... A common misconception in Angular is that importing a module in a parent module (i.e. in your example, AppModule) creates a hierarchy of modules. Hence, people assume AppModule's child modules (i.e. HomeModule) *should* also inherit parent module's imported modules.

**However, that is not the case. Modules *do not inherit* access to modules declared in parent modules.** Imagine a module as a box. A box will only contain whatever you put inside of it.

Now if you have 3 boxes, box A, box M and box H. If you didn't put box M inside the box H, why would box H contain stuff that belongs to box M?

Similarly, if you have put box M and box H inside of box A. Now, box A would certainly contain all the stuff in both box M and box H, wouldn't it?

Now, switch the term "box" to module, and A to AppModule, M to MaterialModule and H to HomeModule. Does it make more sense now?

To further highlight this in Angular applications, that is why when you generate a new module, a CommonModule is automatically imported in the new module. CommonModule is a "lesser" version of BrowserModule, containing NgIf, NgFor, etc directives that are commonly used in components. Because in the new module, BrowserModule is NOT automatically inherited into it - ngIf, ngFor, etc wouldn't work. You can test this out, by removing CommonModule and see if you can use ngFor, ngIf, etc.

---

You can easily fix this by creating a SharedModule to import all of your third-party lib's modules. I.e. importing MaterialModule and then exporting it out.

All your (lazily loaded) feature modules will then have to import one single SharedModule instead of having repeating all the imports for 3rd party modules.

E.g. SharedModule

```js
@NgModule({
   imports:[
       CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule, 
       //... {other modules that will be shared between modules} ...,
   ],
    exports:[
        CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialModule,
        //... {other modules that will be shared between modules} ...,
    ]
})
```

Comment: Great explanation. Btw. isn't a bad practice to use SharedModule? If I will import this module somewhere - there is significant chance that that Module won't require all Modules that SharedModule contains, so it is literally waste of resources. So shouldn't I just Import specific modules that I really need in particular Module?

Comment: Yes it is good practice because SharedModule will load imported modules once and then share instance

Comment: Pardon my previous comments that I have since deleted xD Yes, Amadou is right. You should keep SharedModules as small as possible. If necessary, create multiple smaller SharedModules or just directly import the modules you need to a module. IMO, it really depends on how large of an application you are working on. Rest assured about importing a module twice in 2 different modules. [Angular will cache the module the first time you load it.](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-i-import-the-same-module-twice).

Comment: Anyway, importing your MaterialModule into SharedModule shouldn't be an issue because your MaterialModule contains Material Design components that you'd surely want to be consistent throughout your app. Unless some parts of your app is using another design theme...

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a [SharedModule](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) and then import it wherever you want to use one of his module:

> Creating shared modules allows you to organize and streamline your code. You can put commonly used directives, pipes, and components into one module and then import just that module wherever you need it in other parts of your app.

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ MaterialModule],
    exports:      [ MaterialModule ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Now you can inject the SharedModule everywhere you want, here in HomeModule:

```
@NgModule({
    imports:      [ SharedModule ] // <-- now you can access MaterialModule
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: Please check comment that I wrote in @terahertz answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to skip the import step, you have to add the forRoot() to the module as follows:

```
imports: [
    .....
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ....
  ],
```

EDIT:
Try to add this in your **MaterialModule.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [MaterialModule]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```